# Blessing on Mixed Fruit Salad

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits, vegetables

Does the rule of eker and tafall apply to a fruit salad with fruits and vegtables when their was grapes and other fruits and vegtables inside? Do you have to make a haetz because grapes are one of the shivah minim or not?

Answer (score 1):

7 minnim wouldn't matter.  The only time the nature of the food will affect the ikkar/tafel status is by the 5 minim which, if significant, will take on the status of an ikar (if another food is your subjective ikar, you may now have 2 ikarim).

Additionally, some say that ikar/tofel is the reasoning behind bread/wine exempting other food/drinks.

Comment: I thought when you awnser a questions you are supposed to bring a source

Comment: The halachos of ikar and tafel are clarified in Orech Chaim 212.  Although the app;ications are many, the siman is short enough to get the main concepts.  I recommend culminating your study (if you choose) with a flow chart of the halachos as this will simplify the inyan.

Comment: @154772895663898299874667378828 I don't believe there's any rule that one must bring a source in answers on mi.yodeya. Although it can be helpful...

Comment: A guideline more than a rule. From the FAQ (http://mi.yodeya.com/faq): "Be fair. Be authoritative. "One who says something in the name of its speaker brings redemption to the world" (Avot 6:6). Whenever possible, cite your sources and link them. If a position you present (or someone else presents, for that matter) is a matter of dispute, note as much. If you want to quote material from another website, please follow the Referring and Quoting Guideline." It's always best to bring a source when you can, and it's fine to *politely* request a source when someone doesn't bring one.